# Best way to collect Primitive int, long, double into list

Tags: java, data-structures

Suppose I have a list of Billions of Object which holds multiple fields and I need to collect a int field from these Objects satisfying certain criteria.

As there could be n items(dynamic length data), so I can't directly collect them under an primitive int[] with dimensions set to something.
for eg : `int collect[] = new int[1_000_000_000]` -- will Not work!! 
As it will reserve and waste a lot of memory so I need a dynamic collection Data structure like linkedlist. but problem with them is they will cause a lot of un-necessary auto-boxing and un-boxing, when I will be operating on that int value.

what is the best way to collect them so as that there are no wrappings(Auto- Boxing) of int to Integer {as it will increase unnecessary GC work} and the memory usage is as minimum as possible.

Comment: Count how many of the objects satisfy the condition, and create an array of _that_ size?

Comment: Maybe look into [fastutil](http://fastutil.di.unimi.it/)? I haven't used it, but I must have read that it gives collections for primitive types

Comment: `they will cause a lot of un-necessary auto-boxing and un-boxing`  the are not un-necessary, they have purpose.

Comment: Also, maybe you don't even need to put them in a collection or array, but only to stream them using an IntStream.

Comment: @Sweeper you are talking about two loop iteration, making my program to utilise 2x time than it should be. ah! not an appropriate way to do it

Comment: @SPidey you can't know that in advance. Maybe the time needed to do those two passes and to process the array is way shorter than boxing, making ArrayList copies or allocating LinkedList nodes, traversing the list, unboxing.

Comment: @JBNizet suppose I want multiple  operation to be perform on them, which are lateron decided by some other condition, in that case would stream work.
I think It will again iterate for each operation.
the use case is I want to know if I really have to collect them.

Comment: Implement various solutions, and benchmark them. Yet another possibility is to implement your own resizable int list, like an ArrayList but with an int array rather than with an object array.

Comment: @JBNizet : yes, I am thinking something on similar lines, Instead of just creating a resizable array like an array list do I will have a linked list of multiple arrays where no new double size array will be formed and copied. instead each new array of same size will get appended in the end of the earlier one

Answer (score 0):

May be you can try something like `listOfBillion.stream().filter(your condition here).collect()`